# How to call jade mixin by name?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I have some problems with calling mixes in jade.

There is fragment of my layout:

```
        section.page-content
        if blocks && blocks.content
            each blockProps, blockName in blocks.content
                +blockName(blockProps)
```

I pass these params::

> ```
>   "blocks": {
>         "content": {
>             "menu": {
>                 "items": [
>                     {
>                         "href": "href1",
>                         "title": "title1",
>                         "target": "target1",
>                         "text": "text1"
>                     },
>                     {
>                         "href": "href2",
>                         "title": "title2",
>                         "target": "target2",
>                         "text": "text2"
>                     }
>                 ]
>             },
>             "catalog_structure": {
>                 "items": [
>                     {
>                         "text": "i1",
>                         "href": "i1 href",
>                         "title": "tit"
>                     },
>                     {
>                         "text": "i2",
>                         "href": "i2 href",
>                         "title": "tit"
>                     },
>                     {
>                         "text": "i3",
>                         "href": "i3 href",
>                         "title": "tit",
>                         "items": [
>                             {
>                                 "text": "i3_1",
>                                 "href": "i3_1 href",
>                                 "title": "tit"
>                             },
>                             {
>                                 "text": "i3_2",
>                                 "href": "i3_2 href",
>                                 "title": "tit"
>                             }
>                         ]
>                     },
>                     {
>                         "text": "i4",
>                         "href": "i4 href",
>                         "title": "tit"
>                     }
>                 ]
>             },
> ```

```
        }

    }
```

And i want to call mixin with the name "blockName".
I tryed to call it in different ways.

Please, help me with my question.

Sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 1):

**It is not possible.**

**visionmedia** confirmed a year ago "it's not currently possible no"

Reference:
https://github.com/visionmedia/jade/issues/751